# How to escape double quotes inside escaped doubles quotes inside double quotes?

Tags: bash, escaping, quotes, double-quotes

I try to execute the following command :

```
su -l user1 -c "hive -e \"ALTER TABLE schema1.table1 DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (att1=\"$val\");\""
```

I get the error :

```
FAILED: ParseException line 1:81 cannot recognize input near 'val1' ')' '<EOF>' in constant
```

So the problem here is due to the 2nd level nested double quotes, between which there is the variable `$val` whose value is `val1`.

Can you help me resolve it? And the best is to give me a rule for nested quotes.

Comment: How about `"hive -e \"ALTER TABLE schema1.table1 DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (att1=\\\"val1\\\");\""`?

Comment: Why don't you use single quotes on the outside? Removes one level of escaping.

Comment: @kvantour I have done an edit. Actually I should use a variable $val and not use directly the string val1.

Comment: Wouldn't [variable substitution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution) be a good fit for this kind of task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case, you can use single quotes instead of the internal (currently escaped) double quotes, since single quotes inside double quotes are not special at all.

```
su -l user1 -c "hive -e 'ALTER TABLE schema1.table1 DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION (att1=\"$val\");'"
```

In the general case, you can't always avoid death by backslash escapes.  The general quoting rules are very straightforward; text between single quotes is quoted verbatim, whereas double quotes are weaker but allow you to backslash things which should not be touched by the shell.